# Replace a script by another script in child template with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twig

I have a script in a parent template and the same script with some more info in a child template included in parent. This child template is loaded by an ajax call.

I need to replace the script in parent template by the script in child template dynamically with ajax and then to launch the script.
As of now, I only succeeded in refreshing the specified div in HTML.

Here's my code :

**Parent template** :

```
{% block body %}
    <div id="bodyColapColle">
    </div>
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
    // AJAX to get info and display div dynamically
    function rechargerColleStats() {
        var groupes = document.getElementsByClassName("filled-in");
        var groupesSelected = getSelectedGroupesOf(groupes);
        var colleId = document.getElementById('collapside_colle_form_colles').value;
        var numAdherent = document.getElementById('numAdherent').value;

        var DATA = {groupesSelected: groupesSelected, idColle: colleId, numAdherent: numAdherent};
        var request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{{ path('paces_statistique_calculstatistique_getstatscolle') }}",
            datatype: "html",
            data: DATA,
            success: function (response) {
                document.getElementById("bodyColapColle").innerHTML = response;

                drawGraphRepNoteOfColle();
            }
        });
    }

    //Script to refresh and launch after ajax success
    {% block js %}
        function drawGraphRepNoteOfColle() {
             ....
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

**Child template :**

```
{% block js %}
    <script>
        function drawGraphRepNoteOfColle() {
            ....
        }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: whole concept doesn't make sense. What exactly does *"replace script"* mean to you? provide more specifics about the problem you are trying to solve

Comment: I have a controller which renders the parent template. This template is used to send some infos to another controller which generates the child template with ajax. This child template has some datas I need to generate a google chart dynamically. Each time I try to generate this chart, I have a chart without datas because the script is in parent template which doesn't get updated by ajax. Solution I found is to update the script in parent template by replacing it with the same script with datas from the child template.